# Как открыть в CGI доступ к переменым веб сервера apach? к примеру HTTP_AUTHORIZATION

Tags: apache, lua, cgi, http-заголовки

Искал информацию почему HTTP_AUTHORIZATION  = nil пришел к выводу, что apach не передает некоторые переменные CGI скрипту. Так вот как передать их скрипту ?

Искал решение, но в моем apach не работает.

```
<IfModule alias_module>
    #
    # Redirect: Allows you to tell clients about documents that used to 
    # exist in your server's namespace, but do not anymore. The client 
    # will make a new request for the document at its new location.
    # Example:
    # Redirect permanent /foo http://www.example.com/bar

    #
    # Alias: Maps web paths into filesystem paths and is used to
    # access content that does not live under the DocumentRoot.
    # Example:
    # Alias /webpath /full/filesystem/path
    #
    # If you include a trailing / on /webpath then the server will
    # require it to be present in the URL.  You will also likely
    # need to provide a <Directory> section to allow access to
    # the filesystem path.

    #
    # ScriptAlias: This controls which directories contain server scripts. 
    # ScriptAliases are essentially the same as Aliases, except that
    # documents in the target directory are treated as applications and
    # run by the server when requested rather than as documents sent to the
    # client.  The same rules about trailing "/" apply to ScriptAlias
    # directives as to Alias.
    #
    #ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "/srv/httpd/cgi-bin/"
    Alias /cgi-bin /var/www/cgi-bin
    #Alias /cgit /var/www/htdocs/cgit
    <Directory /var/www/cgi-bin>
    #<Directory /var/www/htdocs/cgit/>
     AddHandler cgi-script .cgi .lua 
     Options ExecCGI
     Require all granted


    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
    //тут потом переставлял по разному такой пример. 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_AUTHORIZATION} !-f
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_AUTHORIZATION} !-d
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
 //но без успешно
        </Directory>
        // и сюда пытался вставить пример
    </IfModule>
```

При перезапуске сервера выдает ошибку

> Invalid command 'RewriteRule', perhaps misspelled or defined by a
> module not included in the server configuration

sudo a2enmod rewrite
a2enmod не найден

дистрибутив slackware 15

Comment: у тебя URL может заканчиваться на .lua?  круто!  а я серверные lua-скрипты в .pl переименовываю )))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://support.deskpro.com/en/kb/articles/missing-authorization-headers-with-apache
Здесь нашел ответ.

Нужно добавить строку

`SetEnvIf Authorization "(.*)" HTTP_AUTHORIZATION=$1`

Я не использую PHP, но мне в CGI пришла переменная окружения с именем  HTTP_AUTHORIZATION